# Add button to Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a `Navigation Drawer` that displays To Do lists, I wish to add a **+** button or a `Floating Action Button` on the bottom right of my Nav. Drawer in order to let my user create a new list. Obviously, this button should only display when the drawer is open.

Here is the `xml` for my drawer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_general"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:title="@string/generalTab" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_daily"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:title="@string/dailyTab" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_groceries"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:title="@string/groceriesTab" />
    </group>

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_about"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:title="@string/aboutTab" />                   
    </group>

</menu>
```

And here is the `xml` containing my `DrawerLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

How may I achieve it?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37591717/how-to-make-focus-to-floatingactionbutton-even-if-the-navigation-drawer-is-open

Comment: add your xml drawer file where the view are.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new item in the end and set `actionViewClass` property to it.

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_general"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:title="@string/generalTab" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_daily"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:title="@string/dailyTab" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_groceries"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:title="@string/groceriesTab" />
</group>

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_about"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:title="@string/aboutTab" />  
<item
        android:actionViewClass="floating_button"
        android:id="@+id/nav_about"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:title="@string/aboutTab" />  


</group>
```

> replace floating_button with full qualified class name of floating button.